# Greiner Field Quantization Mistake in Path Integral proof?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, textbook-erratum

I have absolutely no clue how Greiner finds that the last 3 lines (eq. 17 in my picture) are zero. He somehow substitutes for $(q'-q)/2$ a momentum space position operator, and then he acts the two operators (on the last line in my picture) on the function to the right and gets zero (which clearly isn't the case since the chain rule gives a factor of one half for the partial derivative wrt $q'$). If someone could please explain how this expression simplifies to zero that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there's a factor ${1 \over 2}$ missing going from first line to second line of $(17)$. If you restore it, you then apply both derivatives and see that it gives zero. The way you get the differential operator to appear is precisely to notice that acting with it on the left gives the previous expression. Once you have the derivatives you can then integrate by parts to act on the right and conclude that it's zero.